# How to determine the individual slope values of GPS point features in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, point, arcgis-pro, overlay, slope

I have created a geodatabase raster displaying the slope of a region's terrain and have a number of GPS points which I uploaded into ArcMap (using the GPX to features tool). The points are locations of several animals in the wild, and I wish to work out what incline/slope in metres each point falls on. This is to assess if individuals have preferences for steeper or flatter terrain within their habitat. As my raster file was converted from UTM it is already in metres. I'd ideally like the output to include a list of the points with the corresponding slope in metres in a separate column.

Do I need to perform an overlay function to do this? I am currently using ArcGIS Pro.
I am somewhat familiar with ArcGIS but not to a highly skilled level.

Answer (score 1):

You want the **Sample** tool. This tool takes an input vector layer, such as your points, and extracts values from underlying raster(s). You can choose whether the tool simply grabs the nearest raster cell, or calculates some statistic (median, mean, &c) based on nearby cells.

More documentation can be found on this tool [on Esri's site](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sample.htm).

Note that this tool is not specific to ArcGIS Pro. If you're more comfortable with ArcMap, you can use it there.

Also note that this tool requires the **Spatial Analyst** extension. If you are not licensed to use it, you might consider QGIS's **Sample Raster Values** tool, which is quite similar. You can find more on that in [the QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#sample-raster-values).